# Get Suggested Articles in apex

Tags: apex, rest, lightning-knowledge

I am trying to build a component that shows suggested articles for a given case.
I would like to get the exact same suggested articles as the Knowledge component on record page gets.

The rest api

`/services/data/vXX.X/sobjects/sObject/ID/suggestedArticles?language=articleLanguage`

is doing exactly what I need, but we can't use it because we are already close to the daily api requests limit.

Any idea if it's possible to get the same suggested articles but without the rest call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Search Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_search.htm) has the following method `suggest(searchQuery, sObjectType, suggestions` which can be used

> If the searchQuery returns KnowledgeArticleVersion objects, pass an
> options parameter with a Search.SuggestionOption object that contains
> a language KnowledgeSuggestionFilter and a publish status
> KnowledgeSuggestionFilter.

The [Search.SuggestionOption](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Search_SuggestionOption.htm#apex_class_Search_SuggestionOption) class has an apex example

```
Search.KnowledgeSuggestionFilter filters = new Search.KnowledgeSuggestionFilter(); 
filters.setLanguage('en_US'); 
filters.setPublishStatus('Online'); 
filters.setChannel('app'); 

Search.SuggestionOption options = new Search.SuggestionOption(); 
options.setFilter(filters); 

Search.SuggestionResults suggestionResults = Search.suggest('all', 'KnowledgeArticleVersion', options); 

for (Search.SuggestionResult searchResult : suggestionResults.getSuggestionResults()) {     
  KnowledgeArticleVersion article = (KnowledgeArticleVersion)searchResult .getSObject();   
  System.debug(article.title); 
}
```

There's also an example in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_kb_suggestions.htm) using a VF page/apex.

Comment: nice, didn't know about those =) TIL;

Comment: What's the benefit of this over writing a dynamic SOSL? Feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: quick glance at the doc seems to suggest that the string passed to the method automatically appends an `*` at the end of the last character and there is some cleansing as well, which would otherwise need manual doing when suing dynamic SOSL.